# Проблема с переносом файлов из папки на Python

Tags: python, ос, zipfile

У меня есть простая python программа, которая извлекает из zip архива по указанному пути все файлы, сохраняет их в отдельную папку, потом выдергивает из названия файлов дату и в соответствии с этой датой создает для каждого файла со своей датой новую папку соответствующую этой дате.
Проблема в том, что мой код это делает единоразово. Т.е. после создания папки и перемещения туда соответствующих файлов, я не могу запустить свой код для другого zip архива если там присутствуют файлы с той же датой.
Как сделать так, чтобы, если папка с таким названием уже существует, то к ней просто добавлялись файлы, и программа не пыталась создавать новую папку?

```
import zipfile
import os

# Путь к архиву
archive_path = "C:\\Users\\Doc\\Downloads\\Archive.zip"

# Путь к папке, куда будут извлечены файлы
extract_path = "C:\\Users\\Doc\\Desktop\\Archieves"

# Открываем архив
with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    # Извлекаем все файлы
    zip_ref.extractall(extract_path)

# Получаем список файлов в папке
file_list = os.listdir(extract_path)

# Проходимся по каждому файлу
for file in file_list:
    # Получаем дату из имени файла
    date = file.split('_')[0]

    # Создаем папку с датой, если она еще не существует
    date_path = os.path.join(extract_path, date)
    if not os.path.exists(date_path):
        os.mkdir(date_path)

    # Перемещаем файл в папку с датой
    os.rename(os.path.join(extract_path, file), os.path.join(date_path, file))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: что значит "не могу запустить"?

Comment: @Эникейщик прошу прощения, очень сложно в тексте сформулировать сразу суть проблемы.
Я имел в виду, что выдается ошибка после запуска программы.
А именно такая:
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом

Comment: Ну так это совершенно никак не относится к переносу файлов, к созданию папок и тд. Какой файл занят-то другим процессом?

Comment: @Эникейщик да я сам в недоумении. 
У меня изначально папка Archieves - пустая, после запуска скрпита там создаются 1-2 новые папки (В зависимости от того какие файлы лежат в архиве). То есть скрипт выполнен успешно и теперь в папке Archieves, есть, например, 2 папки ["2024-03-01", "2024-03-02"]
После, я хочу запустить скрипт для нового zip файла(в нем лежат файлы с датой  "2024-03-02", которые должны быть помещены в эту папку), но программа обнаружив что папка уже существует выдает вот такую ошибку и все файлы у меня извлекаются просто в Archieves

Comment: Очень нужна помощь, неделю мучаюсь уже над этим. Если нужно больше информации или я как-то не понятно объясняю, скажите, пожалуйста!!!

Comment: " _программа обнаружив что папка уже существует выдает вот такую ошибку_ " - откуда известно, что программа выдает ошибку именно потому что папка уже существует? Ошибка вообще с существованием папки не связана.

Comment: @Эникейщик я тогда в еще большем заблуждении... Когда я удаляю папку - ошибки нет, а когда папка есть и ошибка есть, вот отсюда я и решил что проблема в этом. А так, никаких процессов то и нет больше по-мимо создания директории уже существующей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если говорить очень коротко, то скрипт пытается перенести созданную папку в нее саму.

Распаковывать нужно во временную папку, чтобы не возникало разных интересных ситуаций вроде этой.

Например:

```
extract_path_temp = r"C:\Users\Doc\Desktop\Archieves_temp"
```

И соответствующим образом подправить другие строчки:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    # Извлекаем все файлы
    zip_ref.extractall(extract_path_temp) # <---

# Получаем список файлов в папке
file_list = os.listdir(extract_path_temp) # <---
```

И здесь:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(extract_path_temp, file), os.path.join(date_path, file))
```

Папку `r"C:\Users\Doc\Desktop\Archieves_temp"` при желании можно удалить после завершения работы скрипта:

```
os.rmdir(extract_path_temp)
```

Стоит еще помнить, что если в двух архивах будут файлы с одинаковыми именами, то тоже будет ошибка, но другая: `FileExistsError`. Как ее решать зависит от автора.

Comment: Дааа, это точно то что я и пытался сделать! Спасибо!!